# How to Zip 'only' files under multiple subdirectories?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, zip, subdirectory

This may be sounding familiar, but its different.
I want a command in terminal that does this -

I have a folder `working` and its structure is something like this -

> working
>
> -100
>
> --1
>
> --2
>
> --3
>
> -200
>
> --1
>
> --2
>
> --3
>
> -300
>
> --1
>
> --2
>
> --3

And each of these `1` `2` `3` folders have around 1000 files.

I want to zip only every 1000 files (zip should not contain their top directories) and put them where ever they are.

Comment: Do you want zip files in 100, 200 300 directories or in 1,2,3?

Comment: I want to zip the files under each of the `1` `2` `3` folders. Such as, if there are files `foo1` `foo2` and `foo3` under folder `1` then it should form a zip under `1` which should have the `foo` files.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
zip -jr myzipfile.zip working
```

`-j` means "junk the directories",
`-r` means "traverse recursively into directories"

I don't know what happens to duplicate filenames in different directories (i.e., files `working/100/1/f` and `working/200/1/f` exist, which `f` survives).

Comment: Will try. And no, there are no duplicates. Thanks!